# "would appreciate hearing your thoughts" phrase

Tags: phrases

> I would appreciate hearing your **thoughts** on this ...

In what situations is this phrase usually used? Formal, informal...?

In contrast to:

> I would appreciate hearing your **opinion** on this ...

Comment: could someone please fix the typo in the word "appreaciate"?  I nearly copy-pasted it into an email :-) (not enough reputation here to make the edit myself)

Answer (score 5):

They mean different things, as I am sure you realise, though they can be  and are used in a similar sense.

'Opinion' is probably the more 'formal' of the two. Asking someones 'opinion' suggests you are looking for a more considered, more formal reply.

Asking for someone's 'thoughts', is more a case of getting their initial reaction, a sounding of their views.

Answer (score 2):

> I would appreciate hearing your thoughts on this ...

This goes for a person you like, or are interested in, or you care about.

And that's why you want them to open up and share, for whatever reason.

> I would appreciate hearing your opinion on this ...

This goes for a person who is considered an expert in that field or at least an intellectually proven personality.

Comment: People ask their (non-expert) friends for opinions all the time.